# Checking for occurances of a pixel

Tags: c, bitmap, pixel, bmp

I have the following code:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef unsigned long dword;

dword bmp_find_xy (dword xp, dword yp)
{
    dword w = 50;
    word bpx = (3*8);
    dword offset = (2+sizeof(BMP)+sizeof(DIB));

    dword row = (((bpx * w) * 4) / 32);
    dword pixAddress = (offset) + row * yp + ((xp * bpx) / 8);

    return pixAddress;
}

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/

dword bmp_dfind_c (BYTE R, BYTE G, BYTE B)
{
    dword w = 50;
    dword h = 50;
    dword size;

    FILE* fp = fopen("picture.bmp", "r+b");
    BYTE* bmp;

    int W, H, i;

    dword row = (((24 * w) * 4) / 32);

    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END); size = ftell(fp); bmp = malloc(size);
    rewind(fp);


    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    bmp[i] = fgetc(fp);

    fseek(fp, 54, SEEK_SET);


    H = h;
    while (H--)
    {
        for(W = 0; W < w; W++)
        {
            if(bmp[bmp_find_xy(W, H)] == B &&
               bmp[bmp_find_xy(W, H)+1] == G &&
               bmp[bmp_find_xy(W, H)+2] == R) {
            printf("%i %i %i pixel first occurance at: x:%i y:%i", R, G, B, W, H); }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 1;
}
```

It seems i have forgotten how the bmp pixels are exactly stored. I know it had paddings.. that i haven't implement in the code. Maybe thats the reason i have problems.
The program detects the pixel only if i put 3 vertical pixels in the image.
The program have to detect the first occurance of the specified pixel.
What am i doing wrong?

How come close(1) because its unclear what am i asking?
I cleary asked:
Why this code acts like that:

> The program detects the pixel only if i put 3 vertical pixels in the image.

Instead of:

> The program have to detect the first occurance of the specified pixel.

And questioned:

> What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

It seems to work if doing it to buffer and then rendering the image.

Comment: Oh i am pretty much aware of how to create a bmp. Its just that code for locating the first rgb-specific pixel.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Please post actual code.

Comment: How are you calling `bmp_find_xy` with three arguments when it's only defined to accept two?

Comment: It is part of a large library im performing for a game engine. I believe just putting the typedefs and you'll be able to compile it.
- Fixed, forgot to remove the function-call argument. I removed that argument here, because i found it for pointless, since i know the width of the image. It is 50x50

Comment: Is `+1` and `+2` supposed to be outside the parentheses?

Comment: Yes. It wouldn't make sense elseway.
But there is the problem though. Im giving it the next byte with +1 and the 3rd byte with +2. But it seems to return the next pixel offset in the next column.

Comment: So.. is something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the values from the header when they are avaiable instead of 'magic' numbers. For example, the width and height of the image and the offset to the start of the pixel data.

For a description of the format, look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

Comment: I know how to build a bmp file. But that has nothing to do with my problem. I use 50x50 for a test image to not make the code compilcated for me and for all of you.

Comment: Without knowing the the contents of the DIB it's hard to know if by not making the code complicated you've introduced an error.

Comment: I am just obtaining the bmp in a buffer `bmp` in which i work.
Has nothing to do with building an actual bmp.

Answer (score 0):

You state you "know" that each row is padded to DWORDs but there is no indication you are *using* this knowledge.

Your image is 50 pixels wide; from the attempt of using "bits per pixels" (`bpx`) [1], I infer the image uses 3 bytes per pixels. Therefore, each row is 150 bytes, **rounded upwards to 152 bytes**. That is why your `bmp_find_xy` function returns the wrong address.

The correct way of calculating the row width is:

1. multiply by *bytes* per pixel;
2. if the result is a multiple of 4, done;
3. else round upwards to a multiple of 4.

Your function, adjusted with this knowledge:

```
dword bmp_find_xy (dword xp, dword yp)
{
    dword w = 50;
    dword offset = 2+sizeof(BMP)+sizeof(DIB); /* SEE [2]! */

    dword row = 3 * w;
    if (row & 3)
    {
        row += 4;
        row &= ~3;
    }
    dword pixAddress = offset + row * yp + xp;

    return pixAddress;
}
```

**NOTES:**

[1] Adjusting for `bpx` is not necessary here. Your image is a 24-bit full colour image, and that translates neatly to 3 bytes, so no need to multiply by 8*3 only to divide by 8 again. Granted, there are BMP files with other numbers of bits-per-pixels, but if you want to have your code work for all possible images, you may want to
a. make sure it works for *this* simple, hardcoded case first; and
b. you read all necessary information out of the structures `BMP` and `DIB`.

[2] Why the `2+` there? This suggests that *either* your sizes of `BMP` and/or `DIB` are off, *or* (very likely) you fudged this because you could not get your code working without.

Comment: +2 because i didn't declare the bmp identificator "BM" in the structure. I know all about BMP and DIB. And as i said.. im probably missing the padding.

Comment: The `BM` identifier is a part of the official structure, and you did not show your own implementation, hence my heads-up about that. Does adjusting for padding as I suggested work?

Comment: One more time to say.. i am not drawing that image from the code. I don't think the code i have for drawing matters here. The image is 50x50 made on paint and im putting random pixel and check if the program will detect it. Also because of some reason the bitwise not operator is not included in the engine im using for the project. Using `!` instead.. i tested it and it doesn't work. bmp_dfind_xy sometimes trully returns the wrong address.. shifted with 1 or 2 bytes.

Comment: Carefully reading your code again, I notice this: `while (H--)` is wrong. It starts at your height `h`, but it should start at `h-1` (i.e., it points to row #50, which is out of range for 0..49). But it does *not* explain why your result seems "shifted", so please go over your actual code again and check for *any* inconsistencies.

Comment: ..because maybe i have to add the padds in `bmp_find_xy` ?

Comment: By fixing the height offset.. now i acts like that:
The program detects the pixel only if i put two vertical pixels on each other. And it doesnt really working since.. i gave it cyan for color but it also detects it if it is white.